# Overriding style of <a> in its nested element

Tags: html, css

I have such a situation:

```
<a href="" class="header">
    <table class="myclass">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Hmmm</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</a>
```

Now, the thing is that I can only manipulate with "myclass" style. Can I change the color of "Hmmm" text when manipulating only "myclass"?

I have tried the following but with no result:

```
.myclass,
.myclass td,
.myclass tr,
.myclass a,
.myclass p {
text-decoration: none; /* Remove underline from header */
color: red;
}
```

Comment: With your code, the text turns `red` for me, so it works fine here - http://cssdeck.com/labs/zkrqjv06

Comment: `.myclass td` should have worked, so what *else* is happening. Have you looked at Web Inspector/Firebug to see where the styles are coming from? As an aside, try: `.myclass td { color: #f00 !important; }`, if that works, then it's a specificity problem (another style is more specific), if it doesn't work then it's a selector problem, and there's a problem (perhaps with casing/spelling) with the selector. If it works, then increase the specificity of your selector, *don't* use `!important` in your stylesheet.

Comment: David Thomas: thanks, adding !important worked, how I can increase the specificity?

Answer (score 0):

give a class to `<td>` aswell:

```
<td class="newStyle"></td>

.newStyle{
color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not call td  with myclass. also check if you have included your css file properly.